# How to wait until the data is fetched and update the state with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I would like to know how can I wait until my data is fetched then update the local component state (I'm using redux).

This is my component

```
class Users extends Component {


    state = {
        localUsers: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchUsers(this.props.selectedGroup);
        /*
        this.setState({localUsers: this.state.localUsers.concat(this.props.users)})
        if I update the state here this is asyncronous code
         so it will be update before the data is fetched */
    }

    render() {
        const users = this.state.users.map((user, key) => {
            return (<div key={key} className="card mt-2">
                <div className="card-body">
                    {user}
                </div>
            </div>)

        })

        return (
            <div data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-example3" data-offset="0">
                {users}
            </div>

        )

    }


}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        users: state.users.data,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        fetchUsers: () =>
            dispatch(fetchUsers())
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Users);
```

How can I update the state after the fetching is done (this.props.fetchUsers is completed)

Comment: Redux Thunk? 
Or simply dispatch whenever your fetchUsers has returned something useful? Also, by the looks of it, you have a promise there (As commented in code). Use .then or async / await,

Comment: if I return a promise then I don't respect the redux structure. the action file handles all promises and call the reducer with a specific action type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use `componentDidUpdate()` which is triggered when the component receives updated props (which you will from Redux).

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchUsers(this.props.selectedGroup); <-- dispatch redux action
}

//triggered when getting updated props
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    if(prevProps.users !== this.props.users){
       this.setState({
          localUsers: this.props.users
       })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: In older versions componentWillRecieveProps serve the same purpose.